# Why int is subclass of number.Number?

Tags: python, numbers

Let's see the following code:

```py
>>> int.__mro__
(<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)

>>> import numbers
>>> issubclass(int, numbers.Number)
True
```

We can see there is no `Number` in `__mro__`, that means `int` does not inherit from `Number`, but why `int` is subclass of the `Number`?

Comment: Sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279561/why-inspect-getmroint-returns-with-no-numbers-number) is asking the same thing. Sadly without an answer.

Comment: `numbers` contains `Integral.register(int)`. `Integral` is an indirect subclass of `Number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number` is an abstract base class (ABC). Normal types can be registered as subclasses of the ABC.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register :

> **register(subclass)**
>
> Register subclass as a “virtual subclass” of this ABC.

The `numbers` module contains the line

```
Integral.register(int)
```

`Integral` is a subclass of `Rational` < `Real` < `Complex` < `Number`.

Therefore `int` is a virtual subclass of `Number`.